# \tableofcontents and \listoffigures help

Tags: table-of-contents, front-matter

I'm trying to format the front matter of a thesis and am running into trouble with both the table of contents and the list of figures.

The current table of contents looks like this:

- List of Figures
- List of Tables
- Chapter
- 1. Introduction
- 2. etc.

What I want to do is get rid of the "Chapter" heading in the above, so right after List of Tables, it starts with "1. Introduction". Any ideas?

Also, for the list of figures. It automatically puts the figure caption when generating the list, but my captions are long. I want to keep them long in the text, but short in the generated list of figures. Is it possible to, say, just include the first sentence of the caption for the list of figures?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short captions for figures in \listoffigures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11579/short-captions-for-figures-in-listoffigures)

Answer (score 19):

Figure captions: Use the optional argument of `\caption`:

```
\caption[short title for list of figures]{long title for text}
```

Getting rid of "Chapter" in the table of contents: You have to provide a working code example or at least give information about your document class and packages.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure how much information you need. I am using a custom class for the thesis. It has some code that modifies the \tableofcontents command, but I'm not sure where to start looking or what more information you need. I notice the "Chapter" line isn't written to the .toc file and I haven't found anything in the class file that seems to control that output. The class also modifies the \chapter command. Would you be able to provide a general direction for me to start looking, or is that not possible without more information?

Comment: Is your custom class available at CTAN or another public website? If not, I can only speculate - maybe the odd "Chapter" entry is inserted by the `\mainmatter` command.