# Short captions for figures in \listoffigures

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

When I use `\listoftables` and `\listoffigures` I get in the list long captions that appear next to the tables/figures.

I would like to use short captions for this list which summarize these captions. Is that common to do? If so, what is one way to do it?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2853/627

Answer (score 326, accepted):

`\caption[Short version for LoF]{Long version to appear next to the figure}`

Comment: although a [bracketed] option is the "standard" latex way of providing a short form, some document classes don't follow this convention.  do check to see what happens rather than taking it on faith.  if you find that the result isn't what you expect, you should be able to get help from whoever wrote (and supports) the document class.