# Distinguish between list of of tables and table

Tags: tables, captions

How can I make the caption of the table different from that what shows up in the "List of Tables"

For figures I used the non-float option with: `\figcaption[short title for the index]{description for your figures}`

I would like exactly the same for a table.

Comment: The normal `\caption[list entry]{actual caption}` macro works the same way, both for `figure` and for `table`

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11579/captions-for-figures-in-listoffigures