# How to reference a figure without making the reference appear in the list of figures?

Tags: cross-referencing

I referenced a figure in its title (ex: figure2.3: Model abc of researcher Jhon [3]). The problem is that the reference appears in the list of figures too as : (ex: Model abc of researcher Jhon [3].........98). Is that a way to keep the reference as it is (in the title) but with making it deseppear in the list of figures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your way to go is

```
\caption[caption_for_listOfFigures]{caption}
```

as proposed here: [Captions for figures in \listoffigures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11579/captions-for-figures-in-listoffigures).