# How can I remove the references name from the list of table of contents. I am writing the Thesis

Tags: table-of-contents

List of Figures

Figure 2.1  Linear System of Membrane and coil (Carlsson 2009) . . . . . . . . . .   6

Figure 2.2  The Six Degrees of Freedom in 3D (McLean 2016) . . . . . . . . . . . .   9

I want to remove my \cite from all figures name in TOC only. Not from the figure heading in chapters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The caption-command also accounts for a short version:

```
\caption[Short version for LoF]{Long version to appear next to the figure}
```

If you enter the title without the citation in the short version, this is what will be shown in the List of figures. 
See also: [Short captions for figures in \listoffigures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11579/short-captions-for-figures-in-listoffigures)