# How to cite a figure such that citation do not show in list if figure

Tags: citing

I have been trying to cite a figure but the citation appears in my list of figure which creating a huge mess in reference number like the reference starts from 4 or 5  as up to 3 citation numbers are already given to the list of figures. How can I add²  citation so that it dooes not appear in the list of figures

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What do you mean exactly with 'citing a figure'? It would be helpful if you can write a small example document that shows the behavior that you ask about, and add the code for this document in your question. Maybe also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11579/short-captions-for-figures-in-listoffigures is related.

Comment: Probably `\caption[short text for lof]{long text including \cite{...}}` helps.

Comment: By Citing a figure I mean  Adding bibliography to a figure that I have taken from someone else

Comment: \begin{figure}[t]
 
 
{\includegraphics[width=2.5in] 
 \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{Small.png}
\cite{list}   
 \end{figure}

Answer (score 2):

My original answer was incorrect as pointed out by @leandriis. I have changed the answer to reflect @leandriis comment.

Use the optional argument to `\caption`

```
\caption[hydro power potential]{\cite{...} hydro power potential}
```

If the optional argument is given then this is what appears in the LoF but not in the caption. The required argument always appears in the document itself.

Comment: Sorry, but this is definitely the other way around. The optional argument of the `\caption` command, if given, is used for the entry in the list of figures while the mandatory argument is used in the text itself.  See: `\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\caption[short text]{long caption text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}`.

Comment: @leandriis Thank you for the correction. I have edited my answer with acknowledgements to you.