# Partial display of figure captions in the list of figures

Tags: captions

Consider the below figure and the caption.

[image]

Now I want to display only part of the caption in the list of figures instead of the entire caption. For example, here I would like to display "Figure 1.3: Burke-Schumann flame structure in mixture fraction space", only in the list of figures. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2853/tableofcontents-and-listoffigures-help

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11579/short-captions-for-figures-in-listoffigures--  added as answer also below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figure captions: Use the optional argument of `\caption`:

```
\caption[short title for list of figures]{long title for text}
```